# Adding XFCE to Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, cinnamon

I installed *mint-meta-xfce* package on an existing Cinnamon installation but it doesn't look anything like a standalone installation of Linux Mint 15 Xfce.  It appears to be using the default Xfce settings.

Is there a better procedure to install xfce to get the Mint eye-candy?

---

Linux Mint 15 Xfce installation:

[image: Linux Mint 15 Xfce]

Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon installation after adding mint-meta-xfce:

[image: Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon plus mint-meta-xfce]

---

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps games
```

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
local-repository.list official-package-repositories.list
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/local-repository.list
#deb file:///usr/share/local-repository binary/
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
```

Comment: Could you show us the _contents_ of `local-repository.list` and  `official-package-repositories.list`?It looks like you are missing some repositories.

Comment: Did you try to `mv /home/liv/.config/xfce4/ /home/liv/.config/xfce4-bak` then `apt-get purge mint-meta-xfce` and `apt-get install mint-meta-xfce`? Maybe the issue is that when you first ran Xfce the Mint eye-candy configs weren't present, and that after you ran it once it used the defaults and stuck to that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not clear what "Mint eye-candy" exactly you're after, and I don't know how to restore exact `Linux Mint 15 Xfce` settings into an existing `Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon` installation. But you can at least do the following.

In an existing `Linux Mint 15 Xfce` installation look into:

- `Settings > Appearance > Style` (looks similar to `Bluebird`)
- `Settings > Appearance > Icons` (but I'd bet a leg that it's `Faenza`)
- `Settings > Appearance > Fonts`
- `Settings > WM > Style` (looks similar to `greybird`)
- `Settings > WM > Style` then hide `Menu` and `Shade` buttons in `Button layout`

Then replicate those settings into an existing `Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon` installation. This may be an ugly hack, but it's a 2min job and you get a desktop much closer to what you'd prefer.

As for the `panel`, it needs only minor modifications (remove the bottom panel, change some plugin positions, add some new items, place the top panel at the bottom, etc.). And the `desktop`, I guess it suffices to `Settings > Desktop > Icons` and uncheck `Home`, `FS`, `Trash`.